# Exchange Online - tracking largest attachments and number of attachments

Tags: office365, exchange-online

I'm trying to find out in my Office 365 organization using Exchange Online 1) Each users' total number of outgoing emails with attachments , 2) The sizes of each of those attachments on outgoing emails.

If the report is limited in number of days going back, that's fine, I can repeat over a few weeks and get an averaged baseline.  Message Trace does not let me search for it directly.  If I do a generic search and click into a result, then I can see the whole Message Size, which is not the same as Attachment Size.

MS Defender Alerts are geared towards Spam+Phish reports , and Email&Collaboration appears to be a paid service.

It is possible for me to set up Rules so that I get emails when attachments go out, potentially based on the size, but I'd rather get a report.